# Unable to convert word doc to pdf using LibreOffice with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, pdf-generation, libreoffice

I'm quite new to laravel, having an issue trying to convert a word doc to pdf via localhost on a MAC with LibreOffice. In the UI when I click download I get an error message saying pdf file does not exist.

I can manually generate a pdf via terminal with:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export Invoice_6.doc
```

But when I use the code below for the application, the application returns Invoice_6.pdf file does not exist and sometimes I get a time-out response:

```
   $fullStoragePath = storage_path('app/' . $filename . '.doc');
     $response = exec("soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir $this->outdir $fullStoragePath");
        Log::info($response);
            return storage_path('app/' . $filename . '.pdf');
```

Comment: What does `Log::info` log?

Comment: It will output the response to a log file.

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException: The file "/Users/stevendornan/Desktop/sports-app/storage/app/invoices/clients/1/Invoice_6.pdf" does not exist in /Users/stevendornan/Desktop/sports-appl/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php:37

Comment: I'm aware the pdf file does not exist because the system is not generating it. The problem is the code won't generate the pdf.

Comment: Are you certain that your shell command works?